# Is Stockfish 11 SuFi 19 still fallible?

Tags: engines

In a Game of SuFi 19 , a Czech Benoni, Stockfish 11 as White could have forced , on move 28 , a line that forced an eight piece endgame on move 59. White would have had Queen , Knight and two advanced pawns vs Queen and Rook . The line was suggested by Stockfish own PV on move 27 , a plan that later abandoned for a small centipawn difference. In the game Stockfish was pressing hard in a pawn up endgame , but cannot overcame the stubborn defense by Leela zero ( at least in that game) and the game ended in a draw. Since I have extensively analyzed the eight piece endgame described above with Houdini 6.02 at d= 38/128 and concluded that it was a win, it should be concluded that Stockfish 11 took the wrong path on move 28. The game was a Czech Benoni defense, and , to be honest , is the only mistake by Stockfish 11 in the current SuFi when Stockfish was not in time trouble. Game 62 SuFi 19. At least even Stockfish 11 is not infallible!

Comment: Did you expect it to be a perfect engine? Yeah, it's the best right now, but Deepmind can come back and crush stockfish

Comment: Note that SF12 is about 100 elo better than SF11

Comment: Which game is it? Can you link?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps worth starting by explaining for the benefit of the majority of chess fans who have no interest in computer chess tournaments that a "game of SuFi 19" is not some new chess variant. "SuFi" stands for "Super Final" and "SuFi 19" is the 2019 computer chess super final tournament.

> Is Stockfish 11 SuFi 19 still fallible?

It's also worth reminding ourselves of the meaning of the word "fallible" and its opposite, "infallible".

"Infallible" means "never makes a mistake" and "fallible" means "makes mistakes".

We are still a very long way away from the day that chess will be solved and so are still a long way away from the day that a chess engine is infallible. Until then all chess engines are fallible. In particular Stockfish 11 is fallible.